# Unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.3.14

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I am trying to build multi-project and this is what my code looks like

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ProjectBuild extends Build {
  lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
    organization := "com.learner",
    version := "0.1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
    resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.14",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % "2.3.14"
    )
  )


  lazy val cluster_simple = project
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
}
```

when I run SBT I get error as

```
> reload
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/harit/IdeaProjects/libs/akka-cluster-investigation/project
compile
[info] Set current project to akka-cluster-investigation (in build file:/Users/harit/IdeaProjects/libs/akka-cluster-investigation/)
> compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/harit/IdeaProjects/libs/akka-cluster-investigation/}cluster_simple...
[info] Updating {file:/Users/harit/IdeaProjects/libs/akka-cluster-investigation/}akka-cluster-investigation...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]     ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]     :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.3.14: configuration not found in com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.3.14: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from com.typesafe.akka#akka-remote_2.11;2.3.14 compile
[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]     Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]         com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.3.14 (/Users/harit/IdeaProjects/libs/akka-cluster-investigation/project/ProjectBuild.scala#L10)
[warn]           +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-remote_2.11:2.3.14
[warn]           +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-cluster_2.11:2.3.14 (/Users/harit/IdeaProjects/libs/akka-cluster-investigation/project/ProjectBuild.scala#L10)
[warn]           +- com.learner:cluster_simple_2.11:0.1.0
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last cluster_simple/*:update for the full output.
[error] (cluster_simple/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.3.14: configuration not found in com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.3.14: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from com.typesafe.akka#akka-remote_2.11;2.3.14 compile
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 17, 2015 12:41:00 PM
>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Maybe you use an old SBT version?

Comment: Your build definition works fine for me. I have tested it with a fresh cache so that all dependencies need to be resolved from scratch. What is your SBT/java/scala version? mine are 0.13.9/1.8.0_51/2.11.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the `~/.ivy2` folder and ran again

```
$ sbt clean compile
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/harit/IdeaProjects/libs/akka-cluster-investigation/project

[info] Set current project to akka-cluster-investigation (in build file:/Users/harit/IdeaProjects/libs/akka-cluster-investigation/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 17, 2015 6:45:10 PM
[info] Updating {file:/Users/harit/IdeaProjects/libs/akka-cluster-investigation/}akka-cluster-investigation...
[info] Updating {file:/Users/harit/IdeaProjects/libs/akka-cluster-investigation/}cluster_simple...
[info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;7 ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.7/scala-library-2.11.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.7!scala-library.jar (1958ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.7/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.7!scala-compiler.jar (11051ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.7/scala-reflect-2.11.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.7!scala-reflect.jar (3520ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.4/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.4.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.4!scala-xml_2.11.jar(bundle) (634ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.11/1.0.4/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.4!scala-parser-combinators_2.11.jar(bundle) (455ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.12.1/jline-2.12.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] jline#jline;2.12.1!jline.jar (333ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.3.14/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.14.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.3.14!akka-actor_2.11.jar (3241ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-cluster_2.11/2.3.14/akka-cluster_2.11-2.3.14.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.akka#akka-cluster_2.11;2.3.14!akka-cluster_2.11.jar (930ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/config/1.2.1/config-1.2.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe#config;1.2.1!config.jar(bundle) (267ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-remote_2.11/2.3.14/akka-remote_2.11-2.3.14.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.akka#akka-remote_2.11;2.3.14!akka-remote_2.11.jar (1571ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty/3.8.0.Final/netty-3.8.0.Final.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] io.netty#netty;3.8.0.Final!netty.jar(bundle) (1249ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.google.protobuf#protobuf-java;2.5.0!protobuf-java.jar(bundle) (542ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/uncommons/maths/uncommons-maths/1.2.2a/uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.uncommons.maths#uncommons-maths;1.2.2a!uncommons-maths.jar (140ms)
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 30 s, completed Oct 17, 2015 6:45:40 PM
```